# How to add random effect into cv.glmnet in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R. Recently I have been trying to build a cross-validation mixed model with lasso penalty. But the cv.glmnet function can only provide "cross validation" and "lasso". How can I add random effect to it? Thanks!